# JavaScript get a String from a specific charackter to a space

Tags: javascript, string

i have a shoutbox and want to a username highlighting in the messages. The Shoutbox look like this:

```
<dl id="sbPosts">
                <dt data-id="1780530" data-user="username">
                    <a href="user/username" class="user">username</a>
                    <time>00:00:00</time>
                </dt>
                <dd data-id="1780530" data-user="username">
                    @username text without highlight
                </dd>
                <dt data-id="1780530" data-user="username">
                    <a href="user/username" class="user">username</a>
                    <time>00:00:00</time>
                </dt>
                <dd data-id="1780530" data-user="username">
                    @username text without highlight
                </dd>
                <dt data-id="1780530" data-user="username">
                    <a href="user/username" class="user">username</a>
                    <time>00:00:00</time>
                </dt>
                <dd data-id="1780530" data-user="username">
                    @username text without highlight
                </dd>
                <dt data-id="1780530" data-user="username">
                    <a href="user/username" class="user">username</a>
                    <time>00:00:00</time>
                </dt>
                <dd data-id="1780530" data-user="username">
                    @username text without highlight
                </dd>
</dl>
```

I only want to highlight the "@" and the text after this to the first space like this: "**@skuhlight** whats your question?"

In the shoutbox i want to add a span around the username like this:

```
<dd data-id="1780530" data-user="username">
    <span class="highlight">@username</span> text without highlight
</dd>
```

Here is the code i tried...

```
  function highlight(username) {
  var element = $('#sbPosts > dd');
  var rgxp = new RegExp(username, '@');
  var res = str.substr(username, ' ');
  var repl = '<dd><span class="highlight">' + username + '</span>';
  element.html(element.html().replace(username, repl));
}
```

Comment: Please review [ask], and update your question to include a [mcve]. As it stands your question reads as a work-order because you haven't shown any code that you've tried.

Comment: please post what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getMatches(input){
    var patt = /@\w+/g;
    return input.match(patt);
}

var arr = getMatches("@paper asdsdsds");
var element = $('#sbPosts > dd');
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var txt = arr[i]; // Text to go inside <span>

    element.html(element.html().replace(txt, '<span class="highlight">' + txt + '</span>'));
}
```

The function searches the input for matches, and the small snippet will help generating elements for each match.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer! This replace ever dd with the first-child dd. So it's not working.. I will edit my post to better show what im trying..